# Use ng-style within a directive termplate

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive with the following template:

```
'<div class="popup">' + //...
```

I need to add an optional width to the popup via a width param specified on the directives scope. I've tried using ng-style:

```
'<div class="popup" ng-style="{'width' : width}">'
```

But I just get unexpected identifier errors because of the single quote marks around the 'width'.

I've even tried escaping them:

```
'<div class="popup" ng-style="{\'width\' : width}">'
```

currently the only thing that works is:

```
'<div class="popup" style="width:{{width}}px">' +
```

Is there any way of using ng-style from within a template

Comment: Do you have any plunker for this?

Comment: Yes I have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o7wsLgqj/ ..none of the suggested answers work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot the " after ng-style?

```
 '<div class="popup" ng-style="{width: width + \'px\'}">'
```